# MongoDB querying nested documents with filters

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, filter, find

My MongoDB document looks something like this -

{

```
"VENDOR_ID": "101",
"NAME": "Test",
"DELETEFLAG": "1",
"DATETIME_MODIFIED": "2021-04-22 05:31:27am",
"CONTACT": [{
    "CONTACT_ID": "111",
    "CONTACT_TYPE": "CONTACT",
    "DELETEFLAG": "1",
    "LID": "197",
    "USER_ID": "101",
    "VALUE": "222222222222"
}, {
    "CONTACT_ID": "222",
    "CONTACT_TYPE": "EMAIL",
    "DELETEFLAG": "1",
    "LID": "197",
    "USER_ID": "101",
    "VALUE": "Test@gmail.com"
}, {
    "CONTACT_ID": "333",
    "CONTACT_TYPE": "CONTACT",
    "DELETEFLAG": "2",
    "LID": "197",
    "USER_ID": "101",
    "VALUE": "444444444444"
}, {
    "CONTACT_ID": "444",
    "CONTACT_TYPE": "CONTACT",
    "DELETEFLAG": "2",
    "LID": "197",
    "USER_ID": "101",
    "VALUE": "888888888888"
}]
```

}

`I want to fetch all the Contacts for which the **DELETEFLAG** is set to 1.` My collection can have multiple vendor documents.

I'm using PHP and fetching all the VENDORS with **DELETEFLAG** set to 1 along with their contacts. My query looks something like this -

```
$filterproduct = array(
                "CONTACT.DELETEFLAG"=>'1',
                "DELETEFLAG" => '1',
                "LID"=>$LID,
          ); 
$resultproduct1 = $this->GetMany($collectionName,$filterproduct,$fetchArr);
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: @Ivan I want to fetch all the Contacts for which the DELETEFLAG is set to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you maybe want this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$CONTACT" },
  {
    $match: {
      "CONTACT.DELETEFLAG": "1",                
    },
  },   
]);
```

Yopu break all documents in contacts with **$unwind** and so, get only new generated documents with CONTACT.DELETEFLAG = 1 with **$match**.